# How do I do a Cross Join when I don't have all the columns I need?

Tags: sql-server, join, cross-join

I have two queries which both create tables that I would like to cross join.

```
SELECT SITA, B, C, Rooms, Datearrived, Market_segment, StayDays as RN, AMTRoom as Rev
   FROM [UKRMC].[dbo].[revenue] rev
   JOIN [UKRMC].[dbo].[Contacts] contacts
   ON rev.hotel_id = contacts.id
   WHERE datearrived between '2017-01-01' and '2017-08-31' and C like '%GB%'
  ORDER BY sita
```

This query gives a table which has each date from 2017-01-01 to 2017-08-31 with each SITA (there are 30 SITA) and each Market_segment (there are 18 distinct Market_segments but each SITA doesn't have all the Market_segments and this is where my problem lies).

My next query is:

```
SELECT SEG       
FROM [UKRMC].[dbo].[Segmentation]
WHERE SEG IN ('RAC', 'BIT', 'BIQ', 'CBI', 'TOF', 'QOF', 'BOA', 'FIT', 'LYO', 'RER', 'OTH', 'NRG', 'XXX', 'CRW', 'BGR', 'BGO', 'LGR', 'LGS')
```

So this gives a table of the 18 Segments.

Now, what I want is a table which has each date from 2017-01-01 to 2017-08-31 with each SITA and each Market_Segment (So each date will have 30 x 18 rows) along with all the other columns from the first query too; B, C, Rooms, StayDays as RN, AMTRoom as Rev.

Of course since all dates and market_Segment/Seg combination aren't in the first table I would like to just output RN and Rev as 0 for these but B, C, Rooms is fixed for each SITA (so will i need another join for the fixed values?)

I hope it makes sense what I need. Any help is appreciated! Here is sample data for the two queries respectively.

```
 SITA    B   C    Rooms  Datearrived Market_segment  RN   Rev
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   TOF            2    45                                                                      
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   BAO            33   30.5                                                                       
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   BGR            11   50                                                                     
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   NRG            52   10                                                                       
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   CRW            20   90                                                                       
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   BIT            7    20                                                                     
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   CBI            0    40                                                                      
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   OTH            10   50                                                                       
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   BIQ            11   60                                                                       
ABZPD   PI  GB   150    2017-01-01   RER            12   65      



**SEG**
RAC       
BIT       
BIQ       
CBI       
TOF       
QOF       
BOA       
FIT       
LYO       
RER       
OTH       
NRG       
XXX       
CRW       
BGR       
BGO       
LGR       
LGS
```

Comment: Can you please include some data for this question.  I don't follow you.

Comment: Don't think you want to use a CROSS JOIN here but a LEFT or RIGHT JOIN... Market_segment in the first query is the same as SEG in the second qeury? i mean is that the relation? it's hard to say without example tables and data.

Comment: Yes, Market_segment in the first query is the same as SEG in the second query @RaymondNijland

Comment: And i think you are using the database SQL-server because off the [dbo] in your query.

Comment: Yes, I am. @RaymondNijland

Comment: I have added sample data now! Hope this makes the question clearer @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The Left Join just gives me the same data but just joins it with SEG .. any other ideas? @RaymondNijland

Comment: No it's not clear what results you want.. so it's hard to suggest a query or idea's... can you add the expected result as formatted text also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `cross join` the `distinct sita, B, C, Rooms, datearrived` with your `SEG` list, and `left join` your original query. I can not tell where the columns are being sourced from in your query, so I am just treating table `t` as your original query.

```
select 
    d.SITA
  , d.B
  , d.C
  , d.Rooms
  , d.Datearrived
  , Market_segment = s.Seg
  , Rn  = isnull(t.rn,0)
  , Rev = isnull(t.Rev,0)
from (
  select distinct sita, B, C, Rooms, datearrived 
  from dbo.t -- whichever table has the above columns
  ) d
cross join (
  select SEG
  from dbo.Segmentation
  where SEG in ('RAC', 'BIT', 'BIQ', 'CBI', 'TOF', 'QOF', 'BOA', 'FIT', 'LYO', 'RER', 'OTH', 'NRG', 'XXX', 'CRW', 'BGR', 'BGO', 'LGR', 'LGS') 
  ) s
left join dbo.t 
  on d.datearrived = t.datearrived
 and d.sita = t.sita
 and s.seg = t.market_segment
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WSFUO57652

returns:

```
+-------+----+----+-------+-------------+----------------+----+-----+
| SITA  | B  | C  | Rooms | Datearrived | Market_segment | Rn | Rev |
+-------+----+----+-------+-------------+----------------+----+-----+
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | RAC            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | BIT            |  7 |  20 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | BIQ            | 11 |  60 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | CBI            |  0 |  40 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | TOF            |  2 |  45 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | QOF            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | BOA            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | FIT            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | LYO            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | RER            | 12 |  65 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | OTH            | 10 |  50 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | NRG            | 52 |  10 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | XXX            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | CRW            | 20 |  90 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | BGR            | 11 |  50 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | BGO            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | LGR            |  0 |   0 |
| ABZPD | PI | GB |   150 | 2017-01-01  | LGS            |  0 |   0 |
+-------+----+----+-------+-------------+----------------+----+-----+
```